# Copy rule of excel cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, conditional-formatting, rule

How can I copy with openpyxl the rule(conditional formatting) from an excel cell to another one(without knowing the rule in advance)?
Or alternatively, how can I retrieve the rule of a cell and set it to a new one?
Thanks